# doctrine migrations bundle not found - symblog

Tags: php, symfony

I have managed to install doctrine migrations via the command line as part of the symfony blog tutorial.

[symblog tutorial part4](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html)

However im now getting class cannot be found error?

```
Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle' not found in /media/sf_projects/symBlog/app/AppKernel.php on line 24
```

However im not sure why im getting it the path looks correct to me see screenshot below?
[image]

Comment: When did you get this error? What have you tried? Did you run `php composer.phar install` sometimes?

Comment: I used the php composer.phar update.  I get said error when I try to add the register bundle line for the mirgations its the next part of the tutorial.

Comment: This means you have added `doctrine-migrations` and `doctrine-migrations-bundle` to your `composer.json` and _then_ you executed `php composer.phar update`?

Comment: yeah thats correct.  Then the next part of the tutorial was to add 
"new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle()" but that has resulted in the error that I got.  I assume the tutorial is a little out of date from the symfony version im using but I want to learn the latest version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it the register path in the new version is

new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle(),

Comment: Robbo_UK , How you check this?

Answer (score 2):

You ought to change this path

```
new Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle() //old path
```

with this one

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle()
```

and it should be right.

I got the same error in Symfony2 standard Edition (i'm using the 2.2 but I think that it's valid also for the 2.1).
If it still doesn't work, you ought to install the git repository.
You can do it through the official Symfony2's tutorial:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html

Comment: for me this is not working saying : PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle' not found

Answer (score 1):

i've submitted PR with this fix

https://github.com/dsyph3r/symblog-docs/pull/43

but seems author is not interesting maintaining it anymore, and the blog website he has up is outdated too regards what is in git, i.e git master has some of the fixes merged, but website is not regenerated.

so you should generate his howto yourself or you get stuck following the tutorial step by step with recent versions of symfony2/doctrine